# Scraping HTML tables using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, html-table

Using the below script I'm successfully returning values from the HTML tables into the workbook from the following links: [link1](https://www.express-supplements.co.uk/catalogsearch/result?p=1&q=Optimum%20Nutrition) and [link2](http://www.dolphinfitness.co.uk/en/optimum-nutrition/). But when I'm trying to use the same script for the following [link3](http://www.bodybuildingwarehouse.co.uk/optimum-nutrition?limit=all), it does not return anything back. I think it is due to complex HTML table structure existing on the website. I believe code requires **.Item(0)** number to be adjusted due to table complexity, please advice.

```
Sub Web_Data()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim topic As HTMLHtmlElement

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://www.dolphinfitness.co.uk/en/optimum-nutrition/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each topic In html.getElementsByClassName("category-products")
        With topic.getElementsByClassName("product-name")
            If .Length Then x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
        With topic.getElementsByClassName("price")
            If .Length Then Cells(x, 2) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next topic
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please make up the script and I will download selenium.

Comment: Which version is it that I'm required to install to make this work? [selenium download page](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: Btw, I took out my comment seeing the link in your script. Is this the link you need to scrape?

Comment: [This is the link that I want to scrape off.](http://www.bodybuildingwarehouse.co.uk/optimum-nutrition?limit=all) but essentially I want to build a database of all three websites to see the prices in one place. But that the link mentioned in this comment that script doesnt work.

Comment: No way. You need to install selenium. Get the latest version. I'll give you the script tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, script did not work only on this [link](http://www.bodybuildingwarehouse.co.uk/optimum-nutrition?limit=all) the rest pages returned the values without kicking back.

Comment: Your script is ready and i got it working but you won't be able to run it now.

Comment: Is it a [Selenium version 3.4.0](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar) that I'm required to download in order to run your script?

Comment: Any version will do. Just make sure that the version you are going to install runs in your machine.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works on every other website i try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very site you mentioned in your post is a bit tricky when it comes to parse the price of different products. Few products have got original price with it and the rest have got special price with them. You can't parse both of them all at once until you apply a technique with your expression. I've written an xpath which is able to deal with them and you will be able to get them all. Here is the script:

```
Sub Body_Building()
    Dim driver As New WebDriver, post As Object

    With driver
        .Start "chrome", "http://www.bodybuildingwarehouse.co.uk"
        .Get "/optimum-nutrition?limit=all"
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each post In driver.FindElementsByClass("grid-info")
        i = i + 1: Cells(i, 1) = post.FindElementByClass("product-name").Text
        Cells(i, 2) = post.FindElementByXPath(".//span[@class='regular-price']//span[@class='price']|.//p[@class='special-price']//span[@class='price']").Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any problem executing the script. Btw, selenium binding with vba doesn't have any property to shun "On error resume next" so i put it before the loop. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have got the idea of how it is done. But I'm getting and error when trying to run the above VBA highlighting the following: **driver as New ChromeDriver** and the error itself: **User defined type not defined**.

Comment: Two things come in my mind to see this. 1. have you installed chromedriver? 2. did you add "selenium type library" in the reference library before execution? Btw, web scraping will be very comfortable if you know how to use selenium cause nowadays you will face lots of sites with javascript injected.

Comment: Sorry that I'm bothering you so much with this but this is completely new thing for me. I'm getting the following error: [imgur](http://imgur.com/a/DHCvS) I have added selenium to the library references so as I have installed ChromeDrivers following instructions [on this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz59GsdvUF8)

Comment: No problem Martin.  Ignore the chromedriver thing for a while. Just tell me- can you run any script using selenium with vba as you said earlier, I meant have you been able to run anything with selenium?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what do you exactly mean by saying can I run scripts using selenium. If I run **web_data** sub on BodyBuildingWarehouse website, VBA successfully scrapes HTML just its not right values returned as there is multiple price table id's. Before I have installed selenium this same  web_data script was returning nothing.

Comment: No no I didn't ask that. Okay, what did you mean by it -"Thank you. Now it works on every other website i try!". I thought you told this about selenium.

Comment: I have downloaded Java SE Runtime Environment 8 and ran a selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar and at this point web_data sub started working on bodybuildingwarehouse website where before running selenium on the machine the same sub did not work for the website.

Comment: Updated the answer. Run it and let me know. This time I didn't explicitly mention chromedriver. Working on my computer flawlessly.

Comment: It still gives me the same run time error 33 for some reason. I guess I havent set it all properly. Would you be able to give me some hints how to set up selenium and chromedriver properly?

Comment: Extremely sorry Martin. I can't walk you through the installation. I did it a long time ago and can hardly remember the process. However, google it again and start it over. When you are done installing, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Actually got it working. The problem was that chrome driver was out of date and selenium could not run it so it required to be updated. [Here is the link how to do it](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/133#issuecomment-263548026) The next question would be is it possible to apply this the above Sub techniques for this link: [Optigura website](https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/). Would it be possible to return into separate rows item name and size with matching price?

Comment: I can see the name and size but can't see the matching price.

Comment: I understand that it is kind of a long shot but see the [snapshot](http://imgur.com/a/USYod) of desired result. When user clicks on available size option at the top right corner price changes below under flavor options. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow. I just saw the elements. Name and size can be parsed very easily without using selenium but in case of price and flavor it is needed to click each item which can't be possible without selenium. So, it will take sometime. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150537/discussion-between-martin-and-smth80).

Comment: Kinda busy, Martin. get back to you soon.

Comment: Please follow the [link to the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404511/scraping-html-with-selenium-while-clicking-options)