# Scraping HTML with selenium while clicking options

Tags: excel, selenium, html-table, selenium-chromedriver, vba

I have got a script which I use to scrape off data from the websites using selenium.

```
    Sub Body_Building()
    Dim driver As New WebDriver, post As Object

    With driver
        .Start "chrome", "http://www.bodybuildingwarehouse.co.uk"
        .Get "/optimum-nutrition?limit=all"
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each post In driver.FindElementsByClass("grid-info")
        i = i + 1: Cells(i, 1) = post.FindElementByClass("product-name").Text
        Cells(i, 2) = post.FindElementByXPath(".//span[@class='regular-price']//span[@class='price']|.//p[@class='special-price']//span[@class='price']").Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Would it be possible to scrape off data from [this website](https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/) using the same or similar technique so the outcome would be like below in the snapshot?

[image]

Please see the VBA working so it matched the desired outcome. Thank you **SMth80**

```
Sub optigura_scraper_v2()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
    Dim elems As Object, post As Object

    driver.Get "https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/"
    [A1:D1].Value = [{"Name","Flavor","Size","Price"}]

    Set elems = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//span[@class='img']/img")
    i = 2

    For n = 1 To elems.Count
        driver.FindElementsByXPath("//span[@class='img']/img")(n).Click
        driver.Wait 1000
        For Each post In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='colright']//ul[@class='opt2']//label")
            Cells(i, 1) = driver.FindElementByXPath("//h1[@itemprop='name']").Text
            Cells(i, 2) = post.Text
            Cells(i, 3) = Split(driver.FindElementByXPath("//li[@class='active']//span[@class='img']/img").Attribute("alt"), "-")(1)
            Cells(i, 4) = driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='price']").Text
            i = i + 1
        Next post
    Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it out. This is certainly not the best technique. However, it will serve your purpose. Btw, the scraper will parse exactly how the data is displayed in that page.

```
Sub optigura_scraper()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
    Dim elems As Object, post As Object

    driver.Get "https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/"
    [A1:D1].Value = [{"Name","Price","Size","Flavor"}]

    Set elems = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//span[@class='img']/img")
    i = 2

    For N = 1 To elems.Count
        driver.FindElementsByXPath("//span[@class='img']/img")(N).Click
        driver.Wait 1000
        Cells(i, 1) = driver.FindElementByXPath("//h1[@itemprop='name']").Text
        Cells(i, 2) = driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='price']").Text
        Cells(i, 3) = Split(driver.FindElementByXPath("//li[@class='active']//span[@class='img']/img").Attribute("alt"), "-")(1)
        For Each post In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='colright']//ul[@class='opt2']//label")
            Cells(i, 4) = post.Text
            i = i + 1
        Next post
    Next N
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm just thinking would it be possible to return size for each item? In general it looks very good.

Comment: Also what do you use to read web page source? F12 on Chrome or Ctrl+U option?

Comment: Clicking right button and selecting inspect element.

Comment: Hey, Martin. Check the update script. Size included. It was a bit difficult to deal with.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out with selenium. I have amended the VBA a little so it matched the desired outcome.

Comment: The one you updated is giving duplicate results and several flavor missing. So, be careful before using the result. Thanks again.

Comment: I have just counted all the flavors and none of them are missing for me yet.

Comment: Yeah. Now it is giving the right results.

Comment: Okay Martin, good luck on your scraping activity. I hope you enjoyed so far with selenium.